# What is this whitish jelly-like substance on a branch?

Tags: species-identification, botany, mycology, phycology

[image]

[image]

I came across this whitish jelly-like substance hanging on a fallen branch. I assume it was growing there and I feel like it might be a fungus or algae of some sort, or maybe an egg sack. I was hiking in a mountain rainforest in Hawaii. The area I found it was shady with adequate indirect sunlight, about 65-70°F at the time. There weren't any others nearby and it was the only one like it that I happened upon during the hike. What is this and if it is living, how does it grow, how does it live?

Comment: It is obvious, by the values, that the temperatures you give are not in Celsius degrees, but it would be nonetheless better to add the units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a [*Tremella fuciformis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tremella_fuciformis), which is actually a sort of yeast that produces jelly-like fruiting bodies. AKA the white jelly mushroom.